# Instance pointers in an array

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to save pointers of class instances into a mutable array. I'm able to do this but getting them back into use seems to be a problem. The next is how I inserted the pointers into the array:

```
Class *class = [Class new];
/* Do something with the instance */

[instanceArray addObject:class];
```

I am able to retrieve the wanted index from the array but when I try to access the instance variables etc. I only get compiler shouting at me or sometimes I get every variable as zero.

How am I supposed to get the instance back to use from the array? I know they are pointers but playing with them didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `addObject:` the element is inserted at the end of the array. To retrieve it you can use `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`

Pointer arithmetic works in C since then your array is just a pointer to the first index, and `array[i]` is the same as `*(array + i)`. In Objective-C this may still be done, however you're using an `NSArray` object. Now you don't have a pointer to the first object anymore, but to the instance of the class. To retrieve the objects stored in the array, you'll have to call the corresponding methods.

---

**EDIT**
So you are able to retrieve it from the array and then your pointer is not `nil`, so you do have access to the object. You know in Objective-C, all instance variables are private so you can't access them from outside. You'd have to declare them as properties first (please refer to the documentation). Also, when you declare a variable to be of type `id`, accessing a property with dot-syntax doesn't work, it will cause a compiler error.

Comment: Oh, I the question may have been a bit confusing. I know how to retrieve the indice but the pointer doesn't seem to work anymore. I'll add more to the question.

Comment: Then you're probably calling `objectAtIndex:` on a `nil` pointer, so `instanceArray` has been released and set to `nil`, before having retrieved the object. You can test this with something like `NSLog(@"%p --> %p", instanceArray, [instanceArray objectAtIndex:0]);`.

Comment: When I try `NSLog(@"%@",[instanceArray objectAtIndex:0])`, I get something like `<class = 0806EBC0 | Tag = -1>`. That's how I think the array is alright. How I tried to get my hands to that pointer was `id instance = [instanceArray objectAtIndex:0];` and then try access the variables as I normally would.

Comment: Odd. How are you declaring `Class`?

Comment: Wow, it works now... this didn't seem to work before but now it does. Maybe I wasn't careful enough or was just tired ;) I did this and it works. `id instance = [instanceArray objectAtIndex:0];` and `NSLog(@"%i", [instance integer]);`